# 'std::iter_value_t' : Failed to specialize alias template

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

I have a legacy class that I cannot replace. Call it example_list. I want to add iterators there and use std::views, but I cannot build it under VS2022 if I use a const example_list, as in my main.
Here the simplified code (don't care what's inside my functions):
---- example_list.ixx ---
module;

```
export module example_list_module;

import std;

export template <typename T>
class example_list {
public:
    T* _curr;
    T* _head;

    class iterator {
    public:
        // iterator traits
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    private:
        T* _curr;

    public:
        iterator(T* entry = nullptr)
            : _curr{ entry } {}

        constexpr iterator& operator++() noexcept {
            _curr++;
            return *this;
        }

        constexpr iterator operator++(int) noexcept {
            iterator tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }

        constexpr [[nodiscard]] bool operator==(const iterator& other) const { return _curr == other._curr; }

        constexpr [[nodiscard]] bool operator!=(const iterator& other) const { return !(*this == other); }

        constexpr [[nodiscard]] reference operator*() const { return *_curr; }
    };

    class const_iterator {
        // iterator traits
        using difference_type = int;
        using value_type = const T;
        using pointer = const T*;
        using reference = const T&;
        using const_reference = const T&;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    private:
        const T* _curr;

    public:
        const_iterator()
            : _curr{ nullptr } {
        }

        const_iterator(const T* entry)
            : _curr{ entry } {
        }

        constexpr const_iterator& operator++() {
            _curr++;
            return *this;
        }

        constexpr const_iterator operator++(int) {
            const_iterator tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr bool operator==(const_iterator other) const { return _curr == other._curr; }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr bool operator!=(const_iterator other) const { return !(*this == other); }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr reference operator*() const { return *_curr->_data; }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr pointer operator->() const { return _curr->_data; }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr difference_type operator-(const const_iterator& other) const {
            if (_curr == nullptr)
                return -1;

            int distance = 0;
            auto end = const_iterator{ nullptr };
            const_iterator it = *this;
            for (; it != end && it != other; ++it)
                ++distance;

            if (it == end)
                return other - *this;
            else
                return distance;
        }
    };

    [[nodiscard]] iterator begin() noexcept { return iterator{ this->_head }; }

    [[nodiscard]] const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return const_iterator{ this->_head }; }

    [[nodiscard]] const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return begin(); }

    [[nodiscard]] iterator end() noexcept { return iterator{ nullptr }; }

    [[nodiscard]] const_iterator end() const noexcept { return const_iterator{ nullptr }; }

    [[nodiscard]] const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return end(); }
};
```

And I want to use it like this

```
---- main.cpp ----
import example_list_module;

import std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values;
    example_list<int> vv;
    const example_list<int>& const_vv = vv;
    std::ranges::transform(const_vv, std::back_inserter(values), [](int val) -> int {
        return val * 2;
        });
}
```

The error I get is

```
1>  C:\temporanea\iterator_range\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp(10,15): error C3889: call to object of class type 'std::ranges::_Transform_fn': no matching call operator found
1>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\algorithm(3508,53):
1>  could be 'std::ranges::in_out_result<_It,_Out> std::ranges::_Transform_fn::operator ()(_It,_Se,_Out,_Fn,_Pj) const'
1>      C:\temporanea\iterator_range\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp(10,15):
1>      'std::ranges::in_out_result<_It,_Out> std::ranges::_Transform_fn::operator ()(_It,_Se,_Out,_Fn,_Pj) const': expects 5 arguments - 3 provided
1>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\algorithm(3520,75):
1>  or       'std::ranges::in_out_result<conditional<std::ranges::borrowed_range<_Rng>,unknown-type,std::ranges::dangling>::type,_Out> std::ranges::_Transform_fn::operator ()(_Rng &&,_Out,_Fn,_Pj) const'
1>      C:\temporanea\iterator_range\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp(10,15):
1>      the associated constraints are not satisfied
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\algorithm(3518,19):
1>          the concept 'std::ranges::input_range<const example_list<int>&>' evaluated to false
1>              C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\xutility(2473,42):
1>              the concept 'std::input_iterator<example_list<int>::const_iterator>' evaluated to false
1>                  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\xutility(775,59):
1>                  the concept 'std::indirectly_readable<example_list<int>::const_iterator>' evaluated to false
1>                      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\xutility(688,31):
1>                      the concept 'std::_Indirectly_readable_impl<example_list<int>::const_iterator>' evaluated to false
1>                          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\xutility(678,18):
1>                          'std::iter_value_t' : Failed to specialize alias template
1>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\algorithm(3533,61):
1>  or       'std::ranges::in_in_out_result<_It1,_It2,_Out> std::ranges::_Transform_fn::operator ()(_It1,_Se1,_It2,_Se2,_Out,_Fn,_Pj1,_Pj2) const'
1>      C:\temporanea\iterator_range\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp(10,15):
1>      'std::ranges::in_in_out_result<_It1,_It2,_Out> std::ranges::_Transform_fn::operator ()(_It1,_Se1,_It2,_Se2,_Out,_Fn,_Pj1,_Pj2) const': expects 8 arguments - 3 provided
1>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\algorithm(3551,105):
1>  or       'std::ranges::in_in_out_result<conditional<std::ranges::borrowed_range<_Rng>,unknown-type,std::ranges::dangling>::type,conditional<std::ranges::borrowed_range<_Rng2>,unknown-type,std::ranges::dangling>::type,_Out> std::ranges::_Transform_fn::operator ()(_Rng1 &&,_Rng2 &&,_Out,_Fn,_Pj1,_Pj2) const'
1>      C:\temporanea\iterator_range\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp(10,15):
1>      'std::ranges::in_in_out_result<conditional<std::ranges::borrowed_range<_Rng>,unknow
```

I understood that this happens because I cannot assert this: `static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<const example_list<int>&>);`

and this because I cannot assert this:`static_assert(std::indirectly_readable<example_list<int>::const_iterator>);`
because of this error:

```
1>  ConsoleApplication1.cpp
1>  C:\temporanea\iterator_range\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp(11,21): error C2607: static assertion failed
1>  C:\temporanea\iterator_range\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp(11,21):
1>  the concept 'std::indirectly_readable<example_list<int>::const_iterator>' evaluated to false
1>      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\xutility(688,31):
1>      the concept 'std::_Indirectly_readable_impl<example_list<int>::const_iterator>' evaluated to false
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\xutility(678,18):
1>          'std::iter_value_t' : Failed to specialize alias template
```

Note that when I want to use its instance not as const I can build my example.

How to fix it?

Comment: Short answer: Remove `const` from your `value_type`. I'll elaborate later if no one else does.

Comment: I have removed the value_type of the const_iterator, but I still get the same results

Answer (score 2):

The default member access of a `class` is `private`. That is, when you write

```cpp
    class const_iterator {
        // iterator traits
        using difference_type = int;
        using value_type = const T;
        using pointer = const T*;
        using reference = const T&;
        using const_reference = const T&;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
```

All these member type aliases are `private`, and thus cannot be named from outside the class.

You can fix this by adding `public:` after the opening brace.

Comment: You are right! This was the solution, thanks